# Trying to install Release Management Server for TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management, tfs-2015

Trying to install Release Management Server on a Team Foundation Server 2015 VM, running Server 2012 R2.

The installer will not move from 'Aquiring .Net Framework 4.6'. It fails to download the package from the internet, and instead asks me to point it to the local path '..packages/dotNetFx-Web.exe'.

I have manually installed the .Net Framework 4.6

Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: Does your virtual machine have internet access?

Comment: If it's a VM, is the clock set correctly (so that SSL connections can be secured correctly?)

Comment: Yes, via proxy server - I can browse without issue however I am asked for credentials each time I open a new window. I am receiving no promps from the installer however

Comment: The clock is also set, thanks

Comment: That might be the the issue. You can install .NET framework 4.6 as a stand alone download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The microsoft package 'Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2015 (x86 and x64) - Web Installer (English)' available on the MSDN Subscriber site contains a packages folder per RM element (Server, Client, Deployment). This folder contains the missing packages.